# How can I use console app (.NET Core) on Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core

I can't use console app with .NET Core. I tried download every workload, but I cannot reach it. Everyone tells me to use framework but my course teacher is using console app in .NET Core and I don't want to move forward without solving the problem I'm facing.

Thank you for helping.

[ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alvmv.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are pointing to the correct template. After.Net Core 3.X versions. >=.Net 5 are .net core only.

You just proceed with creating a new project and then you can select the version of your choice.

[image]

Comment: So you're saying I don't need to search for (.net core). Thanks for your help. I finally understood. :)

Answer (score 3):

Long story short:

For the longest time there existed only .NET Framework (and the non-MS implementation of the framework: Mono). .NET Core was released in 2016 as Microsoft's cross-platform .NET solution. Nowadays .NET Framework is being phased out, and .NET Core going forwards is called simply .NET (.NET 5, .NET 6 and so on).

What you see in your screenshot is the correct project template for .NET Core (.NET) workloads.

See the note at the bottom of [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/microsoft-net-and-net-core):

> Beginning with .NET 5.0, Microsoft .NET Core has been rebranded as .NET.